# Understanding Wave Function Evolution in the Dirac Equation for Different Geometries

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, differential-geometry, dirac-equation, differential-equations

I've come to understand that for Schrödinger's equation, you can select an initial wave function within a constant-time space. By allowing it to evolve according to the Schrödinger equation, you can subsequently determine the wave function at a later time point.

In the context of the Dirac equation, I have a question:

What modifications occur within the equation or the evolution process if the initial wave function isn't defined on a flat hypersurface (such as R3
) but is instead situated on a CURVED hypersurface (e.g. a Cauchy surface)?

Thanks in advance!